# Asynchronous Worker in Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, asynchronous

I am creating a Sprint Rest API to collect multiple requests and call yet another API. What I did so far is:

```
final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:9001/";

@RequestMapping("/getCurrency")
public JSONObject GetCurrency(@RequestParam List<String> currencyCode) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(BASE_URL)
            .path("getCurrencyISO")
            .queryParam("q", String.join(",", currencyCode))
            .build()
            .encode()
            .toUri();
    return restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, JSONObject.class);
}
```

It works perfectly, it calls the core API with correct parameters and returns them. I am trying to improve the network traffic for the core API. For this, I am trying to collect all the requests to my API and once my queue reached 10 requests, I will go to core API and get results than return to clients. If I can't fill my queue in 5 seconds, I will simply go to the core API and return to clients.

I need to create an Asynchronous worker for this I believe to check whether the queue is filled or 5 seconds is passed. I am really new to Spring Rest development, what would be a good practice to achieve this?

Comment: Don't you need to return the data back to the client? By doing this bulk query, you will lose the contract with the client.

Comment: @aksappy I do, that's why I need to go to core API after 5 seconds even though queue is not filled yet. SLA for this service is 10 seconds.

Comment: Is the core API somehow broken or legacy that you would need to build this kind of system?

Comment: @Kayaman Core API is developed by another team so it's not possible to touch that system/code.

Comment: Hmm. It might be achieved with a scheduled service with a `fixedDelay = 5000` that empties the queue... perhaps with `CompatibleFuture`s. But this isn't really a regular use case.